# I have Ubuntu desktop installed and trying to set up Plex I want to put the media on a separate drive this is where I'm having trouble

Tags: hard-drive, plex

I have ubuntu installed, I originally only had an SSD to install the OS on, now I want to add 1 and later 2-3 more regular HDDs. I am not sure if I did the first try right, I connected it and formatted it EXt4 and it shows that it is "mounted" and is a "device" the area I think I want it to be in is called places. how can I move it. my goal is to use this 2TB HDD and 1 or 2 others for media and keep the SSD for the OS and essential programs. When I go to the folder my media is in, it doesn't show but if I move it to videos under the place home it does show. What if anything can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track; so far so good!
Open up a terminal & become root:

```
sudo -i
```

Next, find the UUID for your drive: `blkid /dev/sdb1`, copy the result (with your mouse!). I am assuming here that you have only these 2 drives, no USB etc - it may not be sdb otherwise. You should get something like UUID="fgbdjdilyh354dfh"
Then edit /etc/fstab & add (note the lack of quote marks)

```
UUID=fgbdjdilyh354dfh /path/where/you/want/this ext4 defaults 0 0
```

This will put the drive where you want it, at next boot. It will then hide any files already there; so move them to the new drive - you don't want to be root for this step so `exit` (I use CTRL-D ), `cp -R old/location/* new/drive/`, I suggest you remove the originals because they will just clutter your SSD whilst being inaccessible.
You can then either reboot; or, perhaps safer, `sudo umount /new/drive ; sudo mount -a` & check that `df -h` returns a sensible looking layout and the system works.

Comment: Hi I am having trouble following the directions, I went into a terminal and got the UUID but don't know how to edit the /etc/fstab. is it possible for the drive I want to initially use for my media to be formatted and mounted correctly from the begining, in other words can instead of trying to fix something I did wrong can I start over to do it correctly. I am very new to linux and am doing my best to learn coming from a non-command line windows world.

Comment: In general, Ubuntu will auto-mount a new drive under /media, so if you want it elsewhere, you get to tell it manually. `sudo nano /etc/fstab` is a suitable command to edit the file.. it's not so easy from the GUI because that file is protected. You are nearly there!